# Too many associated models for eager_loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, eager-loading

I have a structure of associations like this in my rails application

[image]

I have to display all the associated data in `Z's` `index` page.

So as of now, to handle `N+1`

I have written a scope in the `Z model`:

```
scope :with_associates -> {includes(:A, :B, :C, {D: :F}, :E)}
```

In the controller i use the scope `with_associates` to fetch the data from associated models.

It just not feel right to have so much associated models in the `includes`.
In future, i guess there are more `associations` going to add for `Z` model.

What can be the best way to handle this situation ?